# Fill missing values matching index and columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently having a problem with filling the missing values of my dataframe using a different dataframe.

Data samples:

df1

```
A   B       C
b   1.0     1.0
d   NaN     NaN
c   2.0     2.0
a   NaN     NaN
f   NaN     NaN
```

df2

```
A   B   C
c   1   5
b   2   6
a   3   7
d   4   8
```

I've tried to follow the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748413/fill-missing-values-of-1-data-frame-from-another-data-frame-using-pandas) but it would appear that it is only possible if the values you're looking up is present in both dataframes you're joining.

My attempt

```
mask = df1["B"].isnull()
df1.loc[mask, "B"] = df2[df1.loc[mask, "A"]].values
```

Error:

```
"None of [Index(['d', 'a', 'f'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Expected result:

```
A   B       C
b   1.0     1.0
d   4.0     8.0
c   2.0     2.0
a   3.0     7.0
f   NaN     NaN
```

Also, can it be used it fill two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) here, which is exactly aimed at filling `NaN`s by matching with another dataframe's columns:

```
df1.set_index('A').combine_first(df2.set_index('A')).reset_index()

   A    B    C
0  a  3.0  7.0
1  b  1.0  1.0
2  c  2.0  2.0
3  d  4.0  8.0
4  f  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I didn't know this method existed and that's even less complicated that it looks. Thanks man! Stay at home!